# Angularjs : Call factory twice on same controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I have the following code which is not working as expected, maybe because I am new on angular :)

I want to re-call the same factory function whenever I append a new record to my database, because that factory will give me the DB data updated in order to fulfill my html table.

**The issue**

The factory function **getData()** is not being called on the second time, so I've not been able to update my $scope.dataTable

**controller code**

```
.controller('SomeViewController', function($scope, $routeParams, getData, addData) {

//scope new record
$scope.newRecordName = "";
$scope.newRecordType = "";

//to fulfill html record's table
getData.then(function(result){
    $scope.dataTable = result
})

// submit button calls this
$scope.addRecord = function(){
    addData.record($scope.newRecordName, $scope.newRecordType).then(function(result) {
        if (result == "OK") {
            //refresh scope dataTable
            getData.then(function(result){
                $scope.dataTable = result
            })
        }
    })
}
```

**factory code**

```
factory('getData', function($http) {
    return $http.get('some/url/')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response
        })
})
.factory('addData', function($http) {
    return {
        record: function(name, type) {
            return $http.post('some/url', {Name: name, Type: type})
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response
                })
        }
    }
})
```

**Note** I cannot use $scope.dataTable.push( 'new_record_here' ) because its missing the record's ID from the database and I need that to have a table like:
ID / Name / Type

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your factory to this

```
.factory('dataFactory', function($http){
    return {
        getData : function() {
            return $http.get('some/url/');
        },
        addData : function(name, type){
            return $http.post('some/url/', {Name: name, Type: type});
        }
    }     
})
```

And your controller to this

```
.controller('SomeViewController', function($scope, $routeParams, dataFactory) {

    //scope new record
    $scope.newRecordName = "";
    $scope.newRecordType = "";

    //to fulfill html record's table
    getAllData();

    // submit button calls this
    $scope.addRecord = function() {
        dataFactory.addData($scope.newRecordName, $scope.newRecordType).then(function(result) {
            if (result == "OK") {
                //refresh scope dataTable
                getAllData();
            }
        })
    };

    var getAllData = function() {
        dataFactory.getData.then(function(result) {
            $scope.dataTable = result
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solved my problem. Seems that the service (dataFactory) cannot be called more than once - however if we create a service function (in this example dataFactory.getData) this can be called more than once. Thanks once again